# Scroll smoothly to a specific position close to a cell at an index path in an UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to scroll to an position close to one of my cells in my UITableView.

I do this with this code:

```
myTableView.scrollToRow(at: index,at: .top, animated: true)
```

and after the animation is completed i do:

```
myTableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: myTableView.contentOffset.y + myCloseToCellOffset), animated: true)
```

**The problem however is that the animation is split in two animations and therefor doesn't run smoothly.** Is there anyway to make this to one animation? Or any other way to get the result i want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion this unpleasant pause between the two animations is unpleasant only when the direction of the two scrolls is the same. When it is different (first up, then down) it looks fine to me. So I am proposing the following (maybe there is a simpler solution, but this is what I thought of):

1. Calculate the offset achieved by `myTableView.scrollToRow(at: index,at: .top, animated: true)` by yourself.
2. If this offset change will be in the same direction as there will be on the addition of `myCloseToCellOffset`, just add `myCloseToCellOffset` to it and call `myTableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: myTableView.contentOffset.y + (initalOffset + myCloseToCellOffset), animated: true)` directly
3. If this offset change will differ in direction than the offset change achieved by `myCloseToCellOffset` then make two calls. Firstly `myTableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: myTableView.contentOffset.y + initalOffset, animated: true)` and then `myTableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: myTableView.contentOffset.y + myCloseToCellOffset, animated: true)

I don't know what `myCloseToCellOffset` is, so I suppose it could be positive or negative or zero.

Here is some example implementation, I hope I don't have mistakes and I hope I am verbose enough:

```
enum TableViewChangeDirections {
case upUp
case downDown
case upDown
case downUp
case unimportant
}

extension Double {
/// Rounds the double to decimal places value
    func rounded(toPlaces places:Int) -> Double {
        let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(places))
        return (self * divisor).rounded() / divisor
    }
}
```

Then in your View Controller that holds the table view

```
let numberOfCells = 20
let cellToMakeVisibleIndex = 5
let heightOfCell : CGFloat = 44
let myCloseToCellOffset : CGFloat = 100

var firstDesiredYOffset: CGFloat!
var secondDesiredYOffset: CGFloat!
```

This will find the offset of `scrollToRow`

```
func tableViewOffset(forCellToGoTo cellToGoTo: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    let desiredOffset = heightOfCell * cellToGoTo
    var maxContentOffset = CGFloat(numberOfCells)*heightOfCell - tableView.frame.size.height
    maxContentOffset = (maxContentOffset >= 0) ? maxContentOffset : 0
    return (desiredOffset > maxContentOffset) ? maxContentOffset : desiredOffset
}
```

This will execute the second offset change if the directions are opposite:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if (tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled == false && self.secondDesiredYOffset != nil && self.firstDesiredYOffset != nil && Double(tableView.contentOffset.y).rounded(toPlaces: 2) == Double(self.firstDesiredYOffset).rounded(toPlaces: 2)) {
        self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.secondDesiredYOffset), animated: true)
        self.secondDesiredYOffset = nil
        self.tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
}
```

This will return the directions of the two offset changes:

```
    var changeDirections : TableViewChangeDirections {
    if self.firstDesiredYOffset > self.tableView.contentOffset.y && myCloseToCellOffset >= 0 {
        return .upUp
    } else if self.firstDesiredYOffset > self.tableView.contentOffset.y && myCloseToCellOffset < 0 {
        return .upDown
    } else if self.firstDesiredYOffset < self.tableView.contentOffset.y && myCloseToCellOffset <= 0 {
        return .downDown
    } else if self.firstDesiredYOffset < self.tableView.contentOffset.y && myCloseToCellOffset > 0 {
        return .downUp
    } else {
        return .unimportant
    }
}
```

And finally the place where you make the general offset changes. I put it in a button action, but you put it where you need it to be:

```
 @IBAction func didPressButton(_ sender: Any) {

    self.firstDesiredYOffset = self.tableViewOffset(forCellToGoTo: CGFloat(cellToMakeVisibleIndex))
    self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.firstDesiredYOffset), animated: true)

    switch (self.changeDirections) {
    case .upUp, .downDown:
        self.firstDesiredYOffset = self.firstDesiredYOffset + myCloseToCellOffset
        self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.firstDesiredYOffset), animated: true)
    case .upDown, .downUp:
        self.tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        self.secondDesiredYOffset = self.firstDesiredYOffset + myCloseToCellOffset
        self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.firstDesiredYOffset), animated: true)
    case .unimportant:
        self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.tableView.contentOffset.y + myCloseToCellOffset), animated: true)
    }

}
```